# Spring MVC - JQuery POST Selection From List

Tags: java, jquery, spring-mvc

I have this dynamically loaded list:

```
<ul class="result-class">
            <c:forEach var="offender" items="${offenderlists}">
                <li><div class="result-div">
                <div class="result-img-holder">
                <img class="lazy" src=<c:out value="${offender.linkToPicture}"/> height="120" width="120"/>
                 <span class=result-div-titles>
                OffenderID: </span> <c:out value="${offender.offenderId}"/>
                </div>

                <div class="result-div-oinfo">
                <ul class="info-list1">
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                First Name: </span> <c:out value="${offender.firstName}"/>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Last Name: </span> <c:out value="${offender.lastName}"/></li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Middle Name: </span><c:out value="${offender.middleName}"/>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                DOB: </span>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Sex: </span>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Risk Level: </span><c:out value="${offender.riskLevel}"/>
                </li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Designation: </span>
                </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="info-list2">
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Race: </span></li>
                <li><span class=result-div-titles>
                Ethnicity: </span></li>
                </ul>
                <div class="result-address">
                <span class=result-div-titles>
                Primary Address: </span><br>
                <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.address_line1}"/><br>
                <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.city}"/>, 
                 New York <c:out value="${offender.primaryAddress.zipcode}"/>
                </div>
                </div>
                 </div></li>

            </c:forEach>
            </ul>
```

I have this jquery script that blinks when user selects it and gets the Id within the text:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.result-div').click(function() {
            $(this).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(200);
            var text1 = $(this).parent().text().split(":")[1].split("\n")[0];
            $.post( "frontpage/select", {idx: text1});
//---- above post isn't working as intended!
    });
});
</script>
```

And I want that script to send a post response to my spring mvc backend for an update to current page

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/select", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView goToView (@RequestParam("idx") String idx){

    System.out.println("something "+idx);
 return new ModelAndView ("frontpage") ;
 }
```

But the spring mvc backend doesn't receive the post request.

**Question 1:** Is there a better way to get the ID for the offender other than parsing the text?

**Question 2:** How do I send a POST response with Jquery to Spring backend so that it would update the CURRENT page with new information?

Comment: Is click function getting called?

Comment: 1: open the browser console and see if there are any javascript errors, preventing further code to run.  2: You may use data attribute to store the value you want instead of parsing the DOM.

Comment: Do you use spring security or not ? If you used then by default spring security enable CRSF security. If yous used spring secuirty 3 then look at in docs at http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had no page known as select. And I couldn't make another post request on the same page...

So I ended up using PUT to send a response. So I didn't need another page.

Also The proper syntax for a post in jquery is .post("", {data: data}); for home page not "/" or frontpage/

Answer (score 0):

Please find the below thoughts..

1. There are couple ways to address the issue.

   - You can store the text in a different element like a `p`. then you can use the child function to access the value.
   - Or even better, if you do not want to disturb the existing document structure, you can store the text in a `title` attribute of the `li` element. Then you can use `..parent().attr('title')` to get the value.  (or even, you can add `title` in the `span` itself, so that you dont need to call `parent()`)
2. Check if you have any JS errors in console, or anything is happening in network tab. Syntax seems be correct.